# How to insert new images inside our unsigned apk

Tags: android, apk

is it possible to add new images inside our unsigned apk. Added the image inside in res folder manually. And there is no need to build apk from eclipse. After add image we are able to sign apk and use that apk in our device.if yes then what is the procedures please help me guys

Comment: do you mean the icon image for the apk file? If yes, look into your manifest for <application> tag, `<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/app_logo">`, the android:icon refers to that Icon you will see as apk file icon

Comment: no actually i want insert image manually, not by eclipse project and insert inside the res folder. we just insert inside the apk which is unsigned export via eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

change the file extension from .apk to .zip

open the nameofyourapk.zip

in there you will find the res folder with all the image files from your app. Replace whatever you need.

Comment: I putted inside the res/darwable folder but it is not showing image which are inserted manually

Comment: do the images have the same name like the ones that were already in there to begin with?

Comment: They have to have the exact same name. If its the icon you are looking to replace you can look up their name in the manifest (like described in the comment to your post)

Comment: i do not want to replace any image which is already exist, want to insert different name of image which is not available inside the drawable folder

Comment: thats not possible then. If you want a show an image at some point in the app you have to call it up by code. So you would have to change the source code itself. Can hardly be done after it's compiled. I guess you could try to decompile the whole thing but that would open a whole new can of worms.

Comment: Worked when i put image inside the assets folder because assets folder is checking at the run time and its work for at least one image should be there, thanks guys for your valuable time to consider here

Answer (score 0):

Adding images in res folder or changing icon of .apk file.  This is what I can get from your question. Impossible as it sounds but now, it can be done. There is a software name **APK Edit** which will do your job. here is the [link for the same](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=890199). In this you will also find download link.

Hope this helps.  :)

Comment: Adding images in res folder not for changing the apk icon

Comment: Yes you can do that, just open Apk edit, browse your .apk file, then go in **Details** section, then click on **Browse**. then, there you have it. Edit whatever you want.

Comment: you will sometime notice Browse is not clickable, because it takes time to load, wait for sometime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apktool.

1) Decompile APK file (It will decompile APK file create folder containing Res,manifest and dex files.

```
apktool d Settings.apk
```

2) Insert images into drawable folder

3) Rebuild APK from modified folder.

```
apktool b Settings
```

Following blog contains detail instructions.

http://www.miui-au.com/add-ons/apktool/